# Passing value gives nil even if value does exist

Tags: ios, swift

I tried passing value between viewControllers. But the problem is, the value is always nil.

In firstVC I do:

```
// Create a custom view controller
let ratingVC = RatingViewController(nibName: "RatingView", bundle: nil)

// Create the dialog
let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: ratingVC, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)

ratingVC.selectedTestString = "HELLO"


// Present dialog
self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in the secondVC:

```
var selectedTestString: String! //Unwrapping because I know value does exist

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    print(selectedTestString) //Gives nil

    }
```

I am doing it first time with `.xib` but I think the concept should be the same.

Comment: maybe there is something like weak and strong in obj-c

Comment: can you try making `ratingVC` a `var` from `let`. It might have to do something with a copy of `ratingVC` being passed not a reference (Functional Programming nature of swift). Or better setting the value before creating `popup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set value of `selectedTestString` before creating the dialog, that will resolve the problem.

```
// Create a custom view controller
let ratingVC = RatingViewController(nibName: "RatingView", bundle: nil)

ratingVC.selectedTestString = "HELLO"

// Create the dialog
let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: ratingVC, buttonAlignment: .horizontal, transitionStyle: .bounceDown, gestureDismissal: true)

// Present dialog
self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @Tarvo To add further clarification. Passing `ratingVC` to the `PopupDialog init` is resulting in `viewDidLoad` being called. So setting `selectedTestString` after the creation of `PopupDialog` is too late. You would have realized this if you has used the debugger and set appropriate breakpoints.

Comment: Really Helped Me!!